# Oracle Forms not running on Microsoft Edge (Internet Explorer), Windows 11

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

Everyone,

As I am new in the domain of oracle forms and reports. However, am facing an issue with "oracle forms" from a couple of days, that is when am debugging or running my oracle form it moves on Microsoft Edge (Internet Explorer) and suddenly pops a message screen, as mentioned below:
[image: Popup Message to Run Form]
So, whenever I click on run, it further starts loading in the  normal position and has to display the form but it displays a screen like, as mentioned below:
[image: Here form should be displayed but not]
However, I followed all the prerequisites while installing, and moreover, on windows 10, it works fine, so far when I update my systems to windows (11) in the last week the issue occurred.

I shall be looking forward to your kind response.

**Thanking you,
Regards**

Comment: (I don't know what *exactly* is written there, but) go to Edge's "Tool" menu (three dots ... in upper right corner of the Edge window) and - among the properties - try to find the one that says something like "Start in Internet Explorer mode"; see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else's benefit, the issue is related to the Java JARs being used not being signed or being signed with an obsolete certificate type.  This was answered in the Oracle Forms forum here:

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4505370/oracle-forms-not-running-on-microsoft-edge-internet-explorer-as-all-the-prerequisites-followed